# Как показывать кнопку возврата( в начало страницы) только после того, как проскролили?

Tags: javascript, jquery

тоесть проскролили 2 первых абзаца  - она появляется
в начале страницы - скрыта

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

   window.on('scroll', function() {

   });

   $('.btn-scroll').on('click', function() {
     $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: 0
     }, '300');
     return false;
   });

 });
```

```css
.btn-scroll {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  bottom: 35px;
  right: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: #68bec4;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.3s background-color;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>


<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<button class="btn-scroll">btn</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pageYOffset` - возвращает кол-во пикселей с начала страницы (не знаю как это правильнее объяснить).
Данной строкой мы даем класс `btn-scroll--show` кнопке с классом `btn-scroll`, что означает, что ее нужно показать.

```js
$('.btn-scroll').toggleClass('btn-scroll--show', pageYOffset > 100)
```

Вторым параметром мы можем указать `switch` то есть true/false. Что и возвращает наша проверка `pageYOffset > 100`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on('scroll', function() {
    $('.btn-scroll').toggleClass('btn-scroll--show', pageYOffset > 100)
  });

  $('.btn-scroll').on('click', function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, '300');
    return false;
  });

});
```

```css
.btn-scroll {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  bottom: 35px;
  right: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: #68bec4;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.3s background-color;
}

.btn-scroll.btn-scroll--show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<button class="btn-scroll">btn</button>
```

---

Можно сделать без доп класса, с помощью `.toggle()`, но не забываем, что для кнопки нужно изначально прописать в стилях `display: none`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on('scroll', function() {
    $('.btn-scroll').toggle(pageYOffset > 100)
  });

  $('.btn-scroll').on('click', function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, '300');
    return false;
  });

});
```

```css
.btn-scroll {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  bottom: 35px;
  right: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: #68bec4;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.3s background-color;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<button class="btn-scroll">btn</button>
```

---

Добавлю еще пример, из просьбы в комментариях. За основу возьмем первое решение, с классом.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on('scroll', function() {
    $('.btn-scroll').toggleClass('btn-scroll--show', pageYOffset > 100)
  });

  $('.btn-scroll').on('click', function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, '300');
    return false;
  });

});
```

```css
.btn-scroll {
  position: fixed;
  
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  
  bottom: 35px;
  right: 20px;
  
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  
  z-index: 999;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  background-color: #68bec4;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: background-color .3s, opacity .4s;
}

.btn-scroll.btn-scroll--show {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusamus cupiditate iusto eum odit mollitia vero reprehenderit, ex optio officia, repellendus placeat eligendi earum, aliquid deleniti culpa nobis officiis modi.</p>

<button class="btn-scroll">btn</button>
```

Comment: спасибо огромное)

Comment: а повторить прям в точь в точь можно? или добавить опасити и все? как тут ubc-build.com.ua/en/our-services

Comment: Как-то довольно глупо выглядит, когда кнопка появляется, у нее opacity: 1 и потом только оно начинает плавно появляется. Сейчас добавлю такой вариант.

Comment: Обновил, пропадает теперь тоже плавно, но быстрее.

Comment: супер)  спасибо ))